# Von Neumann ergodic theorem for purely continuous spectrum

Tags: spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics, ergodic-theory

$\newcommand{\1}{1\negthickspace{\mathrm{I}}}$

Von Neumann ergodic theorem states that, if $U(t)$ is a one-parameter group of unitaries acting on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, we have

$$
\lim_{T\to \infty}  \parallel X(T)(\psi) - P_0(\psi) \parallel = 0
$$

for all $\psi\in\mathcal{H}$ where $\parallel \bullet \parallel $ is the norm in $\mathcal{H}$,

$$
X(T) := \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T dt U(t) \, , 
$$

and $P_0$ is the orthogonal projector onto the invariant subspace $V_0$ of $U(t)$, $V_0=\{ \phi\in \mathcal{H} |\, U(t)\phi=\phi \ \forall t\}$.

Although reminiscent of quantum mechanics it is hard to apply the above theorem in a quantum mechanical setting.

In quantum mechanics we evolve states or operators with the adjoint action (respectively Schroedinger and Heisenberg evolution). Let us pick the Heisenberg evolution:

$$
\mathcal{U}(t)[A] :=U(t)^\dagger A U(t) \, ,
$$

where $U(t)=e^{-i t H}$, where $H$ is a self-adjoint (Hamiltonian) operator.
Define, analogously as before,

$$
\mathcal{X}(T) := \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T dt \mathcal{U}(t) \, . 
$$

Let us consider the case where $H$ has purely continuous spectrum (for example the free article on the line).

> **Question** Assume $H$ has purely continuous spectrum, what is
>
> $$
>  \lim_{T\to \infty}  \mathcal{X}(T) = ?$$

*Remarks*

1) Clearly we have, for all $T$, and trace class $\xi$
$$
\mathrm{Tr} \Big (  \mathcal{X}(T)[\xi] \Big )= \mathrm{Tr} \xi
$$

2) It seems that the only invariant operator of $\mathcal{U}(t)$ is the identity $\1$. Unfortunately this operator is not trace class. Hence is not in $B(\mathcal{H})$ seen as an Hilbert space with Hilbert-Schmidt scalar product (which is the setting one would consider when trying to apply the Von Neumann ergodic theorem).

3) In a way the question is: Is there a way to give a meaning to the limit such that it is non-zero?

It seems that this problem should have been well studied but I could not find any reference.

Comment: This is literally the situation the theorem you quoted deals with: you have strong convergence to the projection $P_0$ on the eigenspace of $H$ for eigenvalue $0$ (of course, $P_0=0$ is possible, for example in your situation when there is only continuous spectrum).

Comment: @ChristianRemling yes I understand, but I would also say that $\mathcal{X}(T)[1]=1$ no?

Comment: @ChristianRemling In a way $\mathcal{X}(T)$ "converges" to $P_0 = (I/d)\mathrm{Tr}(\bullet)$ where the dimension of the Hilbert space $d=\infty$. So $P_0=0$ as you say. However If could project  $\mathcal{X}(T)$ onto a finite dimensional space $V$ I could get a finite result. However $V$ should be invariant under $H$... which again is impossible.